# I can't run tests on the test runner with Play 1.2.7

Tags: testing, playframework

I am trying to run some tests using the testrunner module that comes with the Play framework. I am using the 1.2.7 version of Play and when I create new projects everything works fine. However when in this specific project I try to run tests I run into the following error:

```
Internal Server Error (500) for request GET /@tests/BasicTest.class

Execution exception (In {module:testrunner}/app/controllers/TestRunner.java around line 73)
NullPointerException occured : null

play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:237)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at play.jobs.Job.now(Job.java:64)
    at controllers.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:73)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:557)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:508)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:484)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:479)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)
    ... 1 more
```

I haven't modified anything in the BasicTest.java but can't seem to run it. I can't seem to figure out why. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You must move your Controller logic to a Model for be accesible for your Job, this model need not be an entity, could be a new, i hope this help you.

Good Luck